# Does casting shared_ptr<T> to shared_ptr<const T> changes the object it is pointed to?

Tags: c++, overloading, constants, smart-pointers

If I want, for const correctness, to overload a class member returning a member pointer, what is exactly the difference between a `const std::shared_ptr<T>` and `std::shared_ptr<const float>`? For instance, in the following class:

```
class A {
public:
    A() {}
    /* */
    std::shared_ptr<float>           getMemberPtr() { return std::shared_ptr<float>(member); }
    const std::shared_ptr<float> getMemberPtr() const { return std::shared_ptr<float>(member); }
    std::shared_ptr<const float> getMemberPtr() const { return std::shared_ptr<const float>(member); }
    /* */
    void setMember(float _val) { member = _val; }

protected:
    float member;
};
```

Does calling the second overload will change the type of the object it is pointed to, not allowing the setter method to be called afterwards? If not, what exactly is the difference between both return types, and what is the better practice?

Comment: Exactly the same as the difference between `T* const` and `T const*`. That said, constructing a shared pointer from a float makes no sense.

Comment: I used this minimal class as an example only.

Answer (score 1):

> Does casting shared_ptr to shared_ptr changes the object it is pointed to?

No. Casting a pointer does not change the pointed object.

> what exactly is the difference between both return types

It is not possible to modify the pointed object through a pointer to const. It is possible to modify the pointed object through a pointer to non-const.

Note that shared pointer does not have a constructor that accepts a float, so the example program is ill-formed.

Returning a const object (`const std::shared_ptr<float>`) rarely makes any sense.

Comment: I understand the difference between `pointer to const`  and `pointer to non-const`. My question was directed towards the difference between the second and third overloads of the `getMemberPtr()` function. Even though, as you say, it doesn't really make any sense, will it behave like the first or the second? Also, I used float as a minimal example, as the question was more conceptual and not tied to any code problem I have at the moment.

Comment: @joaocandre Second overload is a pointer to non-const. The third overload is a pointer to const. Second behaves like a pointer to non-const and third behaves like a pointer to const. The first overload is a pointer to non-const. So, first and second are the same in that regard, and third is different.